# Magento my first custom module gives 404 not found

Tags: php, magento, module

I'm a beginner in the Magento. I created own first module following a tutorial and I get 404 not found. What did I do wrong?

I have this folder layout:

[image: c:/xampp/htdocs/magento/local/tsg/trial/*]

my `magento/app/local/tsg/trial/etc/config.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <tsg_trial>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </tsg_trial>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <hello_magento>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                     <module>tsg_trial</module>
                     <frontName>hello</frontName>
                </args>
            </hello_magento>
         </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

my `magento/app/local/tsg/trial/controllers/indexController.php`:

```
class tsg_trial_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    public function indexAction() {
          echo 'hello magento';
   }
}
```

my `magento/app/etc/modules/tsg_trial.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <tsg_trial>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </tsg_trial>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my problem, my folder layout has been incorrect, I just copied "local" folder and pasted it to right destination app/code/local. Previously my "local" folder was in the "app" folder.